# Why createCriteria returns so many objects?

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's say I have a class mapped with hibernate, with bunch of properties, an id and no relations many-to-one and it's name is MyClass. What I'm trying to do is get from database all records, so I do such thing:

```
//omitted some code
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
List<MyClass> = session.createCriteria( MyClass.class ).list();
```

For a SINGLE record in database, criteria returns me 13 objects in list. I can't figure why, while this query:

```
//omitted some code
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
List<MyClass> = session.createQuery( "from MyClass" ).list();
```

Works ok, and returns just 1 object. Could somebody explain this to me?

Comment: What are the SQL queries generated by hibernate in each case?

Comment: Does MyClass has some collection property inside  (One-to-many relation) ?

Comment: Does the following return one item:  session.createCriteria(MyClass.class).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ken yea, but quite deep hidden
@Amir thanks for that comment, it helped me to find what was wrong

Well it finds out, that in hibernate mapping file I have small thing, a relation  with another object, which has in it a list defined in hibernate mapping file, and inside this list is defined one-to-many relation, which was causing all the trouble.

From the beginning solution was to use createQuery instead of createCriteria, but I was curious if I don't know something about hibernate, but that was an old programmer mistake